# Updating Lucene index from two different threads in a web application

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I've a .net web application which uses Lucene.net for company search functionality.
When registered users add a new company,it is saved to database and also gets indexed in Lucene based company search index in real time.

When adding company in Lucene index, how do I handle use case of two or more logged-in users posting a new company at the same time?Also, will both these companies get indexed without any file lock, lock time out, etc. related issues?

Would appreciate if i could help with code as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Lucene.Net has inbuilt index locking using a text file. However if the default locking mode isn't good enough then there are others that you can use instead (which are included in the Lucene.Net source code).

Comment: What if there many new contents? Won't it be resource intensive for all the commits?